# 406 Not Acceptable error occurs in form when textarea contains raw html (input type checkbox)

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, character-encoding

406 Not Acceptable error occurs in form when textarea contains raw html (input type checkbox)

Hi guys/gals, very strange problem I'm having. Let me gt right into it:

I tested my site on Windows 7, Xampp 3.0.12 and using localhost everything works as it should...however, after uploading my site to godaddy cPanel, the 406 error began to occur, mentioned this in case it is relevant.

**Problem:**

I have a series of forms, 1 form to upload picture & text, 2nd form to use data from form 1 to fill in form 2 to get appropriate values (these two forms are on page1.php, upon submission of 2nd form that contains textarea fields that are holding html code to be sent to a new .php page (page2.php) the error displays.

After testing further to find the source of the error I find that the forms work properly if input type="" is not included in the textareas upon submission. If these input fields are included the error is thrown.

I have provided the code below that I think is relevant to solving this problem, but if there is something missing, let me know and I will add whatever is needed so we can get to a solution.

**Form 1 looks like:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
//contains input type text, file fields
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

**Form 2 looks like:**

```
<FORM NAME="product-submit-form" ACTION="http://www.mywebsite.com/product-live-demo.php" METHOD="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

//contains input type text, number, and includes textarea fields 
//like this one below.

<div class="textarea-size">
<ul class="result2" contenteditable="true"></ul>
<textarea id="sizes" name="sizes" rows="8" cols="30" title="content">
</textarea>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="" name="submit-demo">
</form>
```

**This is a sample of the code that is being inputed into the textarea fields:**

```
<div class="checkbox-black"><input type="checkbox" id="black" name="Color:_Black" value="Yes"><label for="black" title="Black"></label></div>
```

The code above throws the 406 error, whereas if I simply delete `<input type="checkbox" id="black" name="Color:_Black value="Yes">` then the error does not show.

This strikes me as odd because I have run a javascript that transforms the html code into raw text so it can be submitted in its raw text form properly to be rendered as html code in the next page. So, i just can't see why this particular piece of text is causing an error.

The javascript I have on page1.php with form 1 & 2 is here:

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var el = $(this).closest('.box-checkbox-size').find('.rawHTML-code-insert2');
    var title = el.html();
    var id = el.data('id');
    // If the checkbox is checked, add the item to the ul.
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var html = $("<li/>", {
            title: title,
            text: title,
            id: id
        });
        $('ul.result2').append(html);
    } else {     
        // if the checkbox is unchecked, remove the item from the ul.
        $('li#' + id).remove();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

**On page2.php the form (form 3-demo) looks like this:**

```
<form action="https://mysite.foxycart.com/cart" method="post">

// the foxy cart action value I added but the demo is not meant to be a 
// working version, only a visual representation of what it would look like

<div class="box-checkbox-size">

    <?php echo $_POST['sizes'] ?>

</div>

//other content

<input type="submit" value="" class="submit">
</form>
```

Attempted Solutions:

1.) I tried altering the `accept charset=""` values from utf-8 to ISO-8859-1 and vice versa on the forms but i gave up after trying about 6 different combinations with the forms I have. If this is the root of the error please let me know what values go for which form. thx

2) I also tried adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form 3 but that seemed to have no effect.

3) I researched a little on godaddy and said .htaccess may be a cause but no detailed instructions were provided on how to remedy this type of problem.

This is all I have at the moment, if anyone can offer a solution it would be most helpful.

Thankyou

Comment: Since it work well when you delete the checkbox, I would try to change its name first, and see if that would be an issue. name="Color:_Black" might be the problem.

Comment: The underscore? no, unfortunately it stills throwing the error.

Comment: for what purpose you gave that name? Just try it with simple name, and see the output.

Comment: I tried "Color" and "Color:Black" same error, purpose is for that value to appear in my foxy cart panel, used for packing slips, product detail information, etc..

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error on godaddy
basically change the name of input fields to body1..2..3

http://w2cschool.com/How/How-To-Manage-Not-Acceptable-406-error-On-Godday-Server-/1170

Comment: Helpful answer for me but what could be the reason that by changing field names it works otherwise not?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to a site on your hosting account, the cause of the 406 error is usually due to a mod_security rule on the server. Mod_security is a security module in the Apache web server that is enabled by default on all hosting accounts. If a site, page, or function violates one of these rules, server may send the 406 Not Acceptable error.

You said that it worked fine on your localhost, that means you need to talk to godaddy, and see if they could disable specific ModSecurity rules.

Try this article: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/find-and-disable-specific-modsecurity-rules

Comment: do you know what rule would need disabling in this case? is it 950004 from this source https://forums.cpanel.net/f5/receiving-406-not-acceptable-error-294292.html

Comment: I've never done that before, but I would contact godaddy first if they could do something about it from their end. If not, I follow that guide.

Comment: Godaddy support said they never seen this type of error before, Also tech support said they have no mod security in place for there hosting accounts??? and lastly, said they can't do anything. Repeated the phrase "we don't handle this sort of stuff", I'm like, ok. Godaddy support 0/10

Comment: I see this action="https://mysite.foxycart.com/cart" and ACTION="http://www.mywebsite.com/product-live-demo.php". Try to remove https:// and http://, and see if that will do it

Answer (score -1):

use name="description" or name="message" in your  name attribute ..
Hope This is solved your problem 
Example

```
<textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="30" >
```